# Flatten complex json using Databricks and ADF

Tags: pandas, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have following json which I have flattened partially using explode

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "employee":[
            {
               "employeeType":{
                  "name":"[empName]",
                  "displayName":"theName"
               },
               "groupValue":"value1"
            },
            {
               "employeeType":{
                  "name":"#bossName#",
                  "displayName":"theBoss"
               },
               "groupValue":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "type":{
                        "name":"firstBoss",
                        "displayName":"CEO"
                     },
                     "name":"Martha"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "type":{
                        "name":"secondBoss",
                        "displayName":"cto"
                     },
                     "name":"Alex"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to get following fields:

```
employeeType.name
groupValue
```

I am able to extract those fields and value. But, if name value starts with # like in `"name":"#bossName#",` I am getting groupValue as string from which I need to extract id and name.

```
"groupValue":[
                  {
                     "id":"1",
                     "type":{
                        "name":"firstBoss",
                        "displayName":"CEO"
                     },
                     "name":"Martha"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"2",
                     "type":{
                        "name":"secondBoss",
                        "displayName":"cto"
                     },
                     "name":"Alex"
                  }
               ]
```

How to convert this string to json and get the values.

My code so far:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
db_flat = (df.select(explode("result.employee").alias("emp"))
.withColumn("emp_name", col(emp.employeeType.name))
.withColumn("emp_val",col("emp.groupValue")).drop("emp"))
```

How can I extract groupValue from db_flat and get id and name from it. Maybe use python panda library.

Comment: Which activity are you using in ADF for this operation?

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT we are using ADF to copy the json file to a table in database with the above fields. We used Copy activity, but mapping is failing.

Comment: do you always have 2 elements in `groupValue` or are you looking for dynamic ways

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT It will always have 2 elements. It won't be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Since you see they won't be dynamic. You can traverse through the `json` while mapping like as below. Just identify record and array, specify `index [i]` as needed.

Example:

```
id -->  $['employee'][1]['groupValue'][0]['id']

name --> $['employee'][1]['groupValue'][0]['type']['name']
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Karthik, thanks but in my case there can be several employee. Say if 50 records are fetched mapping individually in the copy activity won't be feasible.  Is there any way to flatten the json in databricks and then use it in the copy activity.

Comment: ah oki, let me see